# Choosing an appropriate statistical test in Multi-Reader Multi-Case (MRMC) Scenario

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, mcnemar-test

I am looking for the most suitable statistical test for the following situation:

I am in a multi-reader multi-case (MRMC) scenario where 6 readers will perform binary classification on the same 165 samples.
There are 2 reading phases in the study: phase 1 where the readers are on their own to annotate and phase 2 where they have the help of an AI, which should increase their performance in accuracy/sensitivity/specificity.

I would like to assess the significance of accuracy/sensitivity/specificity gains between the two phases. To evaluate this gain per annotator, I used a McNemar test, which seems appropriate for the situation. However, I want to perform the same test by aggregating the annotators together to measure the overall gain. I feel that the McNemar test is not suitable in this case as it does not take into account interactions between annotators.
I tried using the Obuchowski-Rockette-Hillis (ORH) method implemented in Python in this repository https://github.com/Google-Health/google-health/tree/master/analysis, and I have some results that I do not understand.

I have divided my analysis into 2 subgroups (the 3 readers with the lowest accuracy gains and the 3 with the highest).

For the group with low gains, I get the following results (Phase 1 vs. Phase 2):

accuracy 0.931 (Phase 1) -> 0.968 (Phase 2), effect = +0.036, CI=(0.0245, 0.048), statistic=6.76, dof=11.14, p-value=2.9e-05.

For the group with significant gains, I get these results:

accuracy 0.915  (Phase 1) -> 0.982  (Phase 2), effect = +0.067, CI=(-0.02, 0.15), statistic=3.01, dof=2.34, p-value=0.078.

I am having difficulty understanding the much lower significance in the group with significant gains. I am especially surprised that if I perform a McNemar test on each reader separately in this group, I get p-values << 0.05.

Do you have any ideas on how to explain these results?
When looking at the metrics calculated by the ORH method, I noticed that the covariance values were lower in the group with significant gains, which affects, among other things, the calculation of the degrees of freedom.

Do you think this method is well-suited to my situation?